# How to know if a page is protected in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7

Ok. I tried searching on the web but I couldn't get what I want.

Suppose there is a jsp that based on the authorization method (BASIC, Form, none etc..) it needs to do something:

```
switch (....) {


    case BASIC:
        ....

    case Form:
        ....

    case none:
        ....

}
```

So how can I get that information?

thanks

Comment: That depends on your authorization mechanism. Is it configured in your `web.xml`, in your Tomcat, are you using spring-security, etc...

Comment: To have security in your servlet you need to confligure web.xml. You do not need to perform any checks in your code.

Comment: I'm not using spring-security. Never heard of that until today.
I am using web.xml for the app. The thing here is how can the jsp know which type of authorization is the webapp using.
Suppose I'm the developer and somebody else deploys the application and that guys has the freedom to choose the authentication method.
But then I need to know what he used to do something in this other page.

Comment: I cannot imagine what would you do with this information except displaying.

Comment: Just an ugly ugly fix in a huge application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getAuthType%28%29):

> `java.lang.String getAuthType()`
>
> Returns the name of the authentication scheme used to protect the servlet. All servlet containers support basic, form and client
>   certificate authentication, and may additionally support digest
>   authentication. If the servlet is not authenticated null is returned.
>
> Same as the value of the CGI variable `AUTH_TYPE`.
>
> Returns:
>     one of the static members `BASIC_AUTH`, `FORM_AUTH`, `CLIENT_CERT_AUTH`, `DIGEST_AUTH` (suitable for == comparison) or the
>   container-specific string indicating the authentication scheme, or
>   null if the request was not authenticated.